# I have created an admin login with PHP but its not working. Can someone guide me through it or offer appropriate amendments?

Tags: php, authentication, admin, login-control, login-script

This is my login form (admin_login.php) with username and password inputs which should then run the login.php script when I hit submit.

```
admin_login.php
//the login form

<?php 

$dbhost = 'xxxxxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxx';

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $con )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('xxxxxx');

?>

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="login.php">

User:<input name="username" type="text">
Pass:<input name="password" type="password">

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

The following piece of code should take the username and password value from the previous file admin_login.php and allow the user to go the admin_control_panel.php if the username and password is the same as the one stored in my database. Else go back to login.

```
login.php
//the action script

<?php

$dbhost = 'xxxxxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxx';

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $con )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('xxxxxx', $con);

$query = "SELECT username FROM users ".
         "WHERE username=\"$username\" ".
         "AND password = \"$password\"";

$result = mysql_query($query, $con);         

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    header("Location: admin_login.php");
else    
    header("Location: admin_control_panel.php");
?>
```

If all is well I should have an admin control panel which I should be able to use like a normal page except only I can access it.

```
admin_control_panel.php
//where I will be able to access the admin panel, only I should be authorized.

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Control Panel</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>You are in the admin control panel</p>
</body>

</html>
`
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello SQL injection. Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions anymore, but instead use PDO or at least `mysqli_*` with proper escaping of user input.

Comment: You are not reading values from the `$_POST` superglobal array could be the very problem …

Comment: What is not working exactly? What's the error message? Try printing out at various points with echo and print_r to see if everything is successful until that point.

Comment: Search google for SQL injection, and how to make a login system with php.

Comment: There is no 'error message' as such it just reloads the admin_login.php form. Could someone restructure my code so that I am able to push on?

Comment: @phpalix thats pretty much what I have been doing all morning except searching 'SQL injection'. Be great if someone could tell me what to insert into my files and where? thanks

Comment: a good start http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php then this http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html as this is mysql search google php escape strings

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting the `$_POST` results. Try:

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM users ".
         "WHERE username='".$_POST[username]."' ".
         "AND password = '".$_POST[password]."'";
```

Also, this is just a guideline. You're open to sql injection and you should look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

You might also need `mysql_data_seek($result, 0);` after `$result = mysql_query($query, $con);`

You need to move the internal result pointer to the beginning with `mysql_data_seek`.

Comment: It's still not working after doing this. Can you see any other errors or mistypes?

Comment: That should be `{$_POST['username']}`; you cannot directly use array subscripts inside interpolated strings. Also, don't forget to quote the subscript index (otherwise it is interpreted as the name of a PHP constant)

Comment: I managed to get this working and I am able to log in but a user is still able to view the directory/pages by simply inputting /admin or /admin/example.php for example and bypassing the login form. I know that I would have to create a session and from their create an if statement which would put the person back to the login. How would I accomplish this, a full explanation of what is required would be beneficial? cheers

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept the answer and post a new question!

Answer (score 0):

$username = $_POST['username'] and same with password.

Comment: He is obviously starting with php, and it might be good idea to point out the sql security concerns here...

Comment: Sean did that already; might aswell just give him the answer instead of telling him that his site is insecure.